# Calculate amount of energy based on height of object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential-energy

How can you calculate the amount of energy an object produces that falls from a particular height?
Or water.

In an eg i would like to know how can you calculate the amount of electricity water can produce at a certain height?

Answer (score 1):

From its potential energy $V=mgh$. If you have 1Kg of water falling from 10meters you can produce at most 100Joules of energy. ( I used $g\approx10m/s^2$).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would like to calculate if I will be able to produce enough electricity to power my house if I have water stored at a height of 12 ft.